# How can we check in android that forcefully stop is called or not?Is there any way?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, autostart

I'm developing Reminder application.It works fine until I reboot or forcefully stop.I have used both the actions in Manifest: `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `QUICKBOOT_POWERON`

and also added the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission, still, my broadcast receiver is not working. Is there any way to solve this issue and to check that forcefully stop is called or not on android through the program.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set an alarm to check if you are ok or not.

Here an example to set AlarmManager ;

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = 
(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
    60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

And in your BroadcastReceiver you need to set your alarm again. You can check your receiver every hour.

So even if your app is forced to stop, you have chance to restart when your alarmmanager checks it.

Comment: thank you for your response @dcan. As I am storing the time in database,to re-set the alarm Should I retrieve the time again or to store it again?

Comment: You dont need to store the time. You just need to set Alarmmanager for example 1 hour later. And your device will handle the rest. 1 hour later, it will call your broadcastreceiver and you can set alarm again for 1 hour later. You dont need to set time like 11:00 or 15:00 etc. You just need to set it as time period.

Comment: Btw, this is to check that forcefully stopped or still working on background. On reminder side, your app will be the same.

Comment: Is it possible to check that forcefully stopped or still working on background? Can you please share code for the same

Comment: As i said. You can start your broadcast receiver every 1 hour to start your reminder broadcast receiver :)